# how to get :through association values in a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, elasticsearch

In one of my models I have this

```
has_many :professionals
has_many :services, :through => :professionals
```

I'm trying to see how I can get values from services

I have columns `service` and `description` in my Service model. I'm using elasticsearch and I'd like to index service model.

```
def service_name
  services.map(&:service)
end
```

I'm not sure if mapping is the correct way, I'm supposed to get a json using this:

```
def to_indexed_json
    to_json( 
      include: { 
        professionals: { 
          only: [:first_name, :last_name]
          },
        services: {
          only: [:service_name]
          }
        }  
      )
end
```

This is what I'm getting

```
     "professionals": [
              {
                 "first_name": "Happy",
                 "last_name": "Gilmore"
              }
           ],
     "services": []
```

Services is getting an empty array. If its a through association, should it be enclosed within professionals?

Need some help on through associations and whats the proper way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `:methods` parameter to include ActiveRecord `instance methods` to JSON output. `:only` and `:except` uses `DB columns only`.

refer: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Try this:

```
def to_indexed_json
  to_json(
    methods: [:service_name],
    include: { 
      professionals: { only: [:first_name, :last_name] }
    }
  )
end
```

and #service_name should be like this:

```
def service_name
  services.pluck(:service)
end
```